# Android Gradle Plugin Error: Failed to resolve variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build

I downloaded and opened a starter code for an Android online course I'm following. The project builds fine but when I run the project I get the following errors.

```
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
```

I am new to android development and android  studio so I do not even know where to start troubleshooting. After checking out some of the questions I happen to understand these type of problems are usually associated with the buil.gradle file so I am including that here.

This is my Build Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.navigation'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"

    // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"

    // Core
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$version_core"

    // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated,  at least even how to locate the cause when I get this type of an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the versions of the libraries

Replace the `$version_kotin` :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.navigation'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.0"
    // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    // Core
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.1"
    // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06"
}
```

I hope this helps....

Answer (score 2):

Add version number in same line instead of $version...

like for your all dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the **versions** of the libraries and the materials you are using .
Instead of `$version_kotlin` replace it with the latest version of the Kotlin.
Do the similar for all the lines.